# Decimal module in Python inaccurate

Tags: python, decimal, pi

```
from decimal import *
Pi=Decimal(3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399373)
print(Pi)
```

Actual output:

```
3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875
```

Output should be:

```
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399373
```

Why does the value change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing in a [floating-point number](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#floating) to the Decimal constructor, and [floating-point numbers are inherently imprecise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/51685) (see also [the Python manual](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)).

To pass in a precise number to the Decimal constructor, pass it in as a string.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal

# bad
>>> Decimal(3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399373)
Decimal('3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875')

# good
>>> Decimal('3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399373')
Decimal('3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399373')
```

If you have a floating-point variable, you can cast it to a string first, then to a Decimal to avoid *some* floating-point imprecision:

```
>>> a = 0.1 + 0.2
0.30000000000000004
>>> Decimal(a)
Decimal('0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125')
>>> Decimal(str(a))
Decimal('0.30000000000000004')
>>>
```

If you need full precision, just work with Decimals all the way:

```
>>> Decimal("0.1") + Decimal("0.2")
Decimal('0.3')
```

Comment: I used this on my calculation but got this error


                                                                                                                       
              `Pi=Decimal("Pi")+(Decimal("sign")*(Decimal("4")/(Decimal("k")* 
(Decimal("k")+Decimal("1"))*(Decimal("k")+Decimal("2")))))
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]`

Comment: `Decimal("k")` and `Decimal("sign")` doesn't make sense.  If you already have data in floating-point variables called `k` and `sign`, do `Decimal(str(k))` and `Decimal(str(sign))`; the `str()` invocation ensures you're triggering Python's floating point stringification, which turns some overly precise floats into a better form.

Comment: @abcbcd That's an entirely different question, but look into `pickle` or `json` for storing and loading arbitrary data instead of trying to modify Python files programmatically.

Comment: i know but i cant make another question for 90 minutes but thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a string to `Decimal()`, not a float, floats are imprecise to begin with. Also, note the following from the Python docs

> Unlike hardware based binary floating point, the decimal module has a
> user alterable precision (defaulting to 28 places) which can be as
> large as needed for a given problem

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 100 #precision

pi = Decimal("3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399373")
print(pi)    #3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399373
```