# How to parse a python decimal value to string without losing its precision or let it change its value?

Tags: python, decimal

Converting a decimal value to string causes it to lose precision or change value, see the following example:

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

# Create a string value of a decimal
value = str(Decimal(97.17312522036036245646))

print(value) # -> 97.17312522036036170902661979198455810546875

# Ideally I would like to get '97.17312522036036245646' or '97.1731252203603624564600000' # based on the precision that I set.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting precision in Decimal class Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27638005/setting-precision-in-decimal-class-python)

Comment: You lost all hope of a precise result the moment you wrote `97.17312522036036245646` as a float value.  You need to pass that to `Decimal()` as a string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python "decimal" package gives wrong results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62927128/python-decimal-package-gives-wrong-results) or [Decimal module in Python inaccurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71661286/decimal-module-in-python-inaccurate)

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to input the decimal number as a string:

```py
from decimal import Decimal

value = str(Decimal("97.17312522036036245646"))

print(value)
```

The output is `97.17312522036036245646`

Answer (score -2):

Another approach is to utilize f-strings and their ability to manipulate strings. First I present the method, then walk through it

```py
def format_float_string(string_value: str, num_decimals: int) -> str:
    # Split the input string into its integer and decimal parts
    number, decimal = string_value.split('.')
    
    # Format the integer part
    formatted_integer = f"{int(number):d}"
    
    # Format the decimal part with the specified number of decimal places
    formatted_decimal = f"{int(decimal[:num_decimals]):0<{num_decimals}}"
    
    return f"{formatted_integer}.{formatted_decimal}"

# Test the function with an example value
test_string = "97.17312522036036245646"
test_decimals = 5
format_float_string(test_string, test_decimals) ----> '97.17312'
format_float_string(test_string, 30) ----> '97.173125220360362456460000000000'
```

Knowing a string representation of a float we can split the number in into the integer and fractional bits. Only the fractional bit needs to be formatted, where we can use `num_decimals` to cut off at the the desired digit by indexing the string. The of the number of decimals are higher than the actual string representation it will be filled with zeros.